# How do I make sure all resources are loaded before running a function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I'm working on a music webapp that plays a random sequence of notes, but I ran into this issue: whenever it was the case that I was going to press play for the first time after the page loaded, the sequence would "choke" before getting on track. I thought maybe that was because the resources are not yet loaded when I press play for the very first time. I guess I was right, did some research, found this preload = auto thing, which seemed to solve this problem. At least, if you refresh or visit the page for the first time and press play immediately, it works just fine. However, if you don't do anything for a while, like 2/3 minutes, the same thing happens. There's a delayed start, as if it's loading the file, and then it awkwardly speeds up like it's trying to catch up with the setInterval timer. I wrote this very simplified version of the code just to illustrate:

```
<button>Play</button>
<audio src="source1.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="source2.mp3"></audio>
<audio src="source3.mp3"></audio>
<script>
    let notes = []
    document.querySelectorAll("audio").forEach(function(note){
        notes.push(note)
    })
    
    function play(){
        let random_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
        note = notes[random_index]
        note.play()
        setInterval(function(){
            note.pause()
            note.currentTime = 0
            play()
        }, 500)
    }
    
    let button = document.querySelector("button")
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        play() 
    })

</script>
```

So my question is how do I solve this? Is there anyway to tell the function to hold until it can actually play the first file? Maybe a DOM event that fires when the resource is buffered and ready? I feel like I can't relly let the timer begin until I have a way to check that, otherwise it will go crazy as usual. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: besides the onload.. did you know there is a [`canplay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) event specifically for this purpose?

Comment: I have tried both canplay and canplaythrough, they don't solve the problem. If I leave the page idle for a couple of minutes and then press play, the sequence stutters. I really don't have any idea what I can do.

Comment: setInterval setting `note.currentTime = 0` every 500ms will cause that

Comment: All the files are 5s long, but the time in between notes is up to the user to choose, so I have to reset the files to make sure they play from the beginning each time. I couldn't figure out a better way to do it. Also, I have tested with just one note, no setInterval or anything, and still, I have to wait almost a second for the audio to start playing. Events like "canplaythrough" or "playing" will fire, but the playback will not have started yet. The problem is always the first play call. I found this post which describes a similar problem, but unfortunately there are no answers:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360591/javascript-audio-in-html5-delay-after-the-first-play-call

Comment: [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) would wait then run, whilst [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will continuously run every 500ms once defined and what makes it worse is your recursively calling it, your need a [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) in there to prevent them stacking up

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write setTimeout, my mistake! setInterval really doesn't make any sense if I'm recursively calling it. Still, I get this delay. Something as simple as just one button with one audio file attached to it will give me the same delay, but only for the first ever play() call, regardless of preload, I don't know what's up with that.

Answer (score 1):

The `load` event is called after the page is fully loaded:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  // Your code
});
```

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is called after the DOM is loaded but before css and img.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I actually need is to make sure all audio files are loaded and ready to use

Comment: I got a small library for working with audio check out [simple-sfx](https://github.com/tamasszoke/simple-sfx/).

Comment: Great, I'll check that out!